# show that $x = \sum_{k= 1}^{\infty} x_{k} e_{k}$ for every $x = (x_{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \in c_{0}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

It is known that $c_{0}$ is a Banach space with norm
$\lVert x \rVert_{\infty} = \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \lvert x_{k} \rvert$.

When proving that dual space of $c_{0}$ is $l^{1}$
is common to show that every functional $f$ in $c_{0}^{*}$ has the
form
$$
f(x) = 
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
x_{k}f(e_{k}), \quad (f(e_{k}))_{ k \in \mathbb{N}} \in l^{1},
$$

where $e_{k}$ is
the sequece that has 1 in position $k$ and 0 elsewhere.
But to do this, it is essential to know that every $x = (x_{k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $c_{0}$ can be represented
as the convergent series (in the norm $\lVert \cdot  \rVert_{\infty}$) $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} x_{k} e_{k}$ in order to use the
linearity and continuity of $f$ . But this fact is not so trivial for me.
Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: same question answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235687/schauder-basis-for-c-0#:~:text=(en)n%E2%89%A51,for%20c0(N).

Comment: Yes, it does!, thanks